# Is the hard drive data recoverable from this MacBook with extreme battery damage?

Tags: hard-drive, battery, hardware, charging

My friend's laptop almost literally blew up while charging. There is extensive battery damage -- see attached photos below.

Is it possible to recover the hard drive?

And/or should they put pressure on Apple to compensate/replace the laptop if they were using a legit not-damaged charger?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What model/year is this? I'm guessing your friend didn't have a backup?

Comment: @benwiggy unknown year, around 2014 to 2017. no backups, correct

Comment: So I can guess it's out of warranty, right?

Comment: @Thinkr correct -- although I just checked and it seems like it may have been part of the "[15-inch MacBook Pro Battery Recall Program](https://support.apple.com/15-inch-macbook-pro-battery-recall)"..!

Comment: @GregSadetsky I don't know if this program is still running but it might be. Do you have the Mac's serial number for you to check availability? There's an option to do that on the article you gave. :) You can access the serial number through icloud.com if you're signed in to your Mac with an Apple ID

Comment: I do have the serial number (thankfully it's still readable) and the recall program's page says that the device "may be covered" which I feel is a good sign. but what does it specifically mean in this case...? what would they replace..?

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a model with the SSD on a separate module, which you can unscrew and remove. (It's the bit below the speaker on the left hand side.) It's therefore no later than 2017.

Apple uses a proprietary 12+16pin module for those SSDs. There are external USB cases for them, but they are expensive. Otherwise, you'll need another Mac of a similar age, c. 2014 to 2017.

I would certainly take it to an Apple Store, and see what they say. I'd recommend being charming and polite in the first instance, rather than storming in and 'demanding your rights', whatever they may be.

Comment: thank you! I checked the serial number and turns out that this computer was affected by the "[15-inch MacBook Pro Battery Recall Program](https://support.apple.com/15-inch-macbook-pro-battery-recall)"

does that change anything? if the computer was affected by the recall, should I be contacting Apple more directly?

Comment: If you can get to an Apple Store, that's the most easy thing. You can contact Apple Support through the website, if you want.